На что заменить MemoryStorage?
import datetime
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

API_TOKEN = ' '
ID_CHANNEL = ' '

# Create a bot instance
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)

# Create a dispatcher instance
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(storage=storage)

# Define the channel ID where you want to post the messages
channel_id = ID_CHANNEL

# Define the times of the day when you want to post the messages
post_times = [
    datetime.time(15, 55),   # 9:00 AM
    datetime.time(14, 0),  # 2:00 PM
    datetime.time(19, 0)   # 7:00 PM
]

# Define the message you want to post
message_text = "Hello, this is a scheduled post!"


# Define a function to send the message to the channel
async def send_message_to_channel():
    await bot.send_message(channel_id, message_text)


# Define a function to schedule the message posting
async def schedule_message_posting():
    while True:
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        if current_time in post_times:
            await send_message_to_channel()
        await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Check every minute

# Start the bot and schedule the message posting
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(schedule_message_posting())
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        loop.close()


К примеру на Redis https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/finite_state_machine/storages.html

Можно использовать встроенное в Aiogram 3.x хранилище Redis:
from aiogram.fsm.storage.redis import RedisStorage
from redis import Redis

redis = Redis()

dp = Dispatcher(storage=RedisStorage(redis))

